# Set prefilled text content in Facebook using SDK via SharePhotoContent

Tags: facebook, sdk

I need to post both text and images on a Facebook wall. For that, I can't use intent sharing because I want to share text too. So I implemented the Facebook SDK. But I still can't see my text content / caption on the wall. Here is my code.

```
 private void publishImage() {
    ArrayList<SharePhoto> sharePhotos = new ArrayList<>();
    int imageFolderSize;
    File  imageFolder = new File(getActivity().getExternalCacheDir(), "attachments/images");
    if( imageFolder.exists()) {
        imageFolderSize = imageFolder.listFiles().length;
        ArrayList<File> attachments = new ArrayList<>();
        if (imageFolder.exists()) {
            Collections.addAll(attachments, imageFolder.listFiles());
        }
        if (imageFolderSize > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < attachments.size(); i++) {
                File file = attachments.get(i);
                if (file.exists()) {
                    if (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(".png")) {
                        try {
                            SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()))
                                    .setCaption("Welcome To Facebook Photo Sharing on steroids!")
                                    .build();
                            sharePhotos.add(photo);
                        }catch (Exception e){
                            RMLog.debug("Execp: e"+e.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    SharePhotoContent scontent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhotos(sharePhotos ).build();
    if(ShareDialog.canShow(SharePhotoContent.class))
    {
        shareDialog.show(scontent);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Succsesfully posted on your wall",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem ? What happens when you run the code ? Do you get error message ?

Comment: You are __not allowed__ to prefill this - the user has to type it in. You need to go read Facebook’s [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) - 2.3 is the relevant point here, _“Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing. You may use our Share Dialogs to prefill a single hashtag in a post, but don't prefill any content a person didn't create via the API.”_

Comment: hi..SuperPeanut , im not getting any error message. The posted images are shown fine. The problem is showing caption in the wall. i have seen some developers suggested me to use facebook sdk for showing the text content., but here i have used sdk as they said, but nothing happens.

Comment: thank you ...CBroe.

Comment: @GraceVenkat hi i have a same issue i want to share photos with Wall text. if you resolved this issue please share with us.

Comment: @ Hardik Vasani, Hi we can not pre fill any text content in facebook wall as per the fb policy. But there is an other way too, which is setQuote("Your text Here");

Comment: ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
        .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com"))
        .setQuote("Connect on a global scale.")
        .build();